# PHP XMLRPC server without extension

Tags: php, xml-rpc, pingback

I'm trying to create a pingback script for our website, however 1&1 does not have the XMLRPC extension that we require installed.

Are there any alternatives to creating a pingback/trackback script without the need of this extension - and are there any demos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [phpxmlrpc](http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/)

An old Php implementation and it seem to be abandoned, but you can see how to use it to send pingbacks or receive them in this [blogpost](http://www.quietearth.us/articles/2006/10/30/Coding-your-own-blog-Pingback-in-php).

### [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.xmlrpc.html)

There is a pure php implementation of XML-RPC [client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.xmlrpc.client.html) and [server](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.xmlrpc.server.html) in the Zend framework, you can use it to call or implement a pingback service, and it's well documented. If you don't want to use the full framework only as a component library, just download the framework, extract the lib/Zend from it to a directory and include the component's top level file. (you might want to set up autoloading for convenience)

The pingback service description is [here](http://www.hixie.ch/specs/pingback/pingback#TOC3).

If you have that set up, you can go to this [blogpost](http://www.quietearth.us/articles/2006/10/30/Coding-your-own-blog-Pingback-in-php) for pointers for client/server codes, i give you some examples with the Zend classes (the post uses the xmlrpc extension)

#### Sending pingbacks:

```
require_once 'Zend/XmlRpc/Client.php'; // path to the framework files
try {
    $client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('<pingback service url>');
    $client->call('pingback.ping', array('<source uri>', '<target uri>'));
} catch (Exception $e) {
   // error handling
}
```

The service url will be in the blog post's http header, or in a meta tag, described in the [pingback documentation](http://www.hixie.ch/specs/pingback/pingback#TOC2).

#### Pingback service skeleton

```
class PingBackService {
    public function ping($source, $target) {
        $source_url = $source[0];
        $target_url = $target[0];

        // validate parameters here, see http://www.quietearth.us/articles/2006/10/30/Coding-your-own-blog-Pingback-in-php for pointers

        return 'Pingback registered. May the force be with you';
    }
}
require_once 'Zend/XmlRpc/Server.php';
try {
    $server = new Zend_XmlRpc_Server();
    $server->setClass('PingBackService', 'pingback');
    echo $server->handle();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // handle errors
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I could just pull bits out of Zend. Sweet!

Answer (score 0):

PEAR has the [XML_RPC2 package](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_RPC2) which implements an XML-RPC client and server in PHP userland without any needing a special extension.